# Make a special grid with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to make a `grid`(cell size is 1cm x 1cm, the total size of the grid is 26cm x 17cm) by `tikz` because tikz can control size precisely. Please see the attached figure(yes, the final effect requires inverse image）for details about the grid. It's a bit hard for me. Anyone can help me with this? Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,geometry}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) grid +(26,17);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do whatever you can first, it's usually easier for us to fill in the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\foreach` for the labels and ticks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,geometry}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm,paperwidth=29cm}
\begin{document}
{\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=-1,transform shape]
    \draw [gray!10] (0,0) grid +(27,18);
    \draw [black!80] (1,0) grid +(26,17);
    \foreach \lt [count=\n from 1] in {Q,...,A}
        \node at (0.5,\n-0.5) {\lt};
    \foreach \num [count=\n from 2] in {1,...,26}
        \node at (\n-0.5,17.5) {\num};
    \foreach \loc in {1.2,1.4,...,26.8}
        \draw (\loc,6) -- +(0,0.15);
    \foreach \loc in {1,...,27}
        \draw [very thick] (\loc,6) -- +(0,0.25);
    \foreach \loc in {0,0.2,...,16.8}
        \draw (14,\loc) -- +(-0.15,0);
    \foreach \loc in {0,...,17}
        \draw [very thick] (14,\loc) -- +(-0.25,0);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! And how to get an inversed image of the picture by tikz as my attached figure showes?

Comment: Please do care about code indentation.

Comment: @lyl `\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=-1, transform shape]` works.

Comment: Many thanks @muzimuzhi Z